# Equivalent behaviour for template template arguments to function templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-templates, boost-optional

I am trying to write code like this:

```
template <typename K, typename T, template <typename, typename> class C>
boost::optional<T> search(const C<K, T>& dict,
                          const K& key)
{
  auto it = dict.find(key);

  if (it != dict.end()) {
    return it->second;
  } else {
    return boost::none;
  }
}
```

The hope was to be able to call the above function on a variety of containers `(std::[unordered_][multi]map)` with the dictionary interface like:

```
std::map<std::string, Foo> strToFoo;
auto val = search(strToFoo);
```

I know that function templates do not allow template template parameters. But is there another way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: "*I know that function templates do not allow template template parameters.*" What? Why do you think this? The only problem with your code is that `(std::[unordered_][multi]map)` all have more than two template parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the containers that you want this to work for - `(unordered_)(multi)map` - have 4 or 5 template parameters, while your code only expects 2. Use template template parameters and variadic templates together to allow for the extra template parameters.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, 
          template <typename, typename, typename...> class C, 
          typename... Args>
boost::optional<Value> search(const C<Key, Value, Args...>& dict,
                              const Key& key)
{
  auto it = dict.find(key);

  if (it != dict.end()) {
    return it->second;
  } else {
    return boost::none;
  }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bf979701bc2afc7)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a compiler right now, but I think something like this would work:

```
template <typename T>
boost::optional<typename T::mapped_type> 
search(const T& dict, const typename T::key_type& key)
{
  auto it = dict.find(key);

  if (it != dict.end()) {
    return it->second;
  } else {
    return boost::none;
  }
}
```